# Adding an array to state of parent component

Tags: arrays, api, reactjs, state, soundcloud

I'm currently working with the Soundcloud API and  I'm trying to store the users that are returned into an array and then setState the array onto the parent object. The problem is when I console.log the updated state it shows it contains an array but it is empty. Below is an example  of my code:

```js
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){

  return {search : '',
          avatar : '',
          }

  },

  onChange: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({search: e.target.value});
    console.log('does this work', this.state.search)
  
  },

  onClick: function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();

  },

   getData: function(){
    var userAv = [];
    SC.get('/users', { q: this.state.search, limit: 10 }, function(users){
    _.each(users, function(obj){
        userAv.push(obj);
    });
   
    console.log('What is userAv', userAv);
    
  

  })
   this.setState({ avatar: userAv}, function(){
          console.log('What is this.state.avatar', this.state.avatar)
    
   });
},

  render: function(){
      return (
          <div id='search-container'>
          <input
            onChange={this.onChange}
            id='search-bar'
            type = 'text'
            value={this.state.search}
            placeholder = 'Search For Artist here'
            />
          <button
            id="search-button"
            onClick={this.getData}
            type = 'button'>
            Submit
            </button>
            <UserList />

          </div>
              )
  }
});
```

Comment: The only time you update `this.state.search` is with `e.target.value()`. I don't see where you're doing `setState({search: <array>}`. Or are you trying to update `avatar`?

Comment: I'm trying to update avatar

Comment: I see. Well, in any case, note that `<input>` tags are [special in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) and need to be handled differently than regular elements. This might be affecting your program too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying get values from async request outside of callback that is wrong, move `setState` inside callback

```
SC.get('/users', { q: this.state.search, limit: 10 }, function(users) {
  this.setState({ avatar: users });
}.bind(this));
```

also chnage `avarar` in `getInitialState` to `Array` from `String`